# Teclado Touchscreen - Limitar o número de caracteres inseridos em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em um teclado touchscreen, coloquei os números de 0 a 9, tecla limpar e entrar. Conforme os números são clicados eles aparecem em um display.

Para capturar os números clicados estou usando a seguinte função:

```
function addNumber(e){
    var v = $( "#PINbox" ).val();
    $( "#PINbox" ).val( v + e.value );
}
```

Como faço para limitar em 5 a quantidade de números capturados?
Ex.: 12345 e não aceita mais números.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Você está usando algum framework? Somente html + javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma é usar um [operador ternário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria) no `.val()`. Se o número de caracteres for menor que 5, irá concatenar o valor atual + o número clicado, caso contrário irá manter os 5 números alcançados:

```js
function addNumber(e){
   var v = $( "#PINbox" ).val();
   $( "#PINbox" ).val( v.length < 5 ? v + e.value : v );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="PINbox" type="text" readonly>
<br><br>
<button value="1" onClick="addNumber(this)">1</button>
<button value="2" onClick="addNumber(this)">2</button>
<button value="3" onClick="addNumber(this)">3</button>
<button value="4" onClick="addNumber(this)">4</button>
<button value="5" onClick="addNumber(this)">5</button>
<button value="6" onClick="addNumber(this)">6</button>
<button value="7" onClick="addNumber(this)">7</button>
<button value="8" onClick="addNumber(this)">8</button>
<button value="9" onClick="addNumber(this)">9</button>
<button value="0" onClick="addNumber(this)">0</button>
<br><br>
<button onClick="$('#PINbox').val('')">Limpar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar se o campo já contém o limite de caracteres definido a cada iteração.

```
function addNumber(e){
    var v = $( "#PINbox" ).val();
    if( v.length < 5 )
        $( "#PINbox" ).val( v + e.value );
}
```

Caso esteja trabalhando com `HTML` também pode tentar definir um range para o campo (não tenho certeza que vai funcionar neste seu caso). Assim você pode adicionar um atributo `max` que irá especificar o maior número possível que você pode inserir.

```
<input type="number" max="99999" />
```

Se você adicionar um `max` e um `min`, poderá especificar o intervalo de valores permitidos:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99999" />
```

Comment: O `<=` está incorreto. Deveria ser apenas `<`, senão vai aceitar 6 caracteres.

Comment: Verdade @Sam, corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Cara, nem precisa do `else return false`... só o `if` já resolve.